# ios xcode : checking live updates using a .net API

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, nstimer

I'm trying to look for a way as to how I can notify a user of new updates based off of a .Net API that I created. Much like that notification you get on facebook, I just need to alert the user that something has been updated. So I'm thinking I need a function that runs in the background while my user uses the app combined with a NSTimer.

Based on my research (and on this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/14835300/639713)  apparently you can only achieve such a thing for VOIP and location services. And that using push notification is the only way. Is it really the only option that I can use for such a need? Or are there any other ways?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. **While your app is open, poll the server every so often to see if there are any updates to report.**

   This will work only as long as the user has your app open, and as you note, your app will only be allowed to stay open for a long time if it happens to be a VOIP or navigation app.
2. **Use push notifications to push updates to the user’s device.**

   The disadvantage here is that you will need to write some server-side code to talk to Apple’s push notification servers (as described in [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12)). This may or may not be a big deal in your particular situation, but it’s the only way to get data to the user when your app isn’t open.

Comment: Well, I was the one who created the API I can easily do that, I'm a little wary about the "Gotchas" part where the user might not get the notification. Also my user will just need the notification (or alert) when they open up the app. So I think for the additional cost I have to pay for push,it isn't worth it. I'm curious about the first one though, do you know of any links where I can read about it? tutorials is greatly appreciated, but whatever is available. Thanks!!

Comment: So I wasn't really sure if I understood the link correctly, is push notification free? Or do I need to pay a fee?

Comment: push notifications is completely free (you already pay a fee for your dev account..). You can also use push notifications while your app is active. Your app delegate will recieve new notifications when they arive and could handle or dispatch its content based on your app logic. (and you could include an alert to display if the app is not active on the users device)

Comment: @gdubs Option 1 is what you already mentioned: run an `NSTimer` to poll your server every ten seconds or whatever.

Comment: @MartinUllrich so I just read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057635/push-notifications-for-iphone-app-paid-subscription and the answer said I would need to create my own server or pay a subscription to a third party provider. Which is more cost efficient then? I just need to push quick notifications but would need to push from 1 - 6 ipad units maybe once in 2 months.

Comment: well i guess that you already have your own server where you want to get information from?.. For a .net based solution, you could use PushSharp (https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) to hand the notifications over to apple

Comment: Well I have a .net site where i have restful API's that modifies data which I made for the ipad app. Any changes on the .net site either through the site itself or through the API I want a notification sent. I guess I can just trigger that during each transaction? Thanks for the link btw!